# populate a textview from an already inflated layout with a Hashmap

Tags: android

Good day, Hope title is not confusing and i can be clear here. I have a custom ArrayAdapter with TextViews and ImageViews. now i want one of the TextView to be populated by values from a HashMap which have the 2nd columns as the Keys. the structure is just like this..

image1  shop  text2

image2  cars  text2

image3  House text2

image4  boats text2

In this example, the 1st and 2nd columns have already been populated with arrays in the ArrayAdapter. so i want the text2, to be populated with a HashMap of values of which column2 are the keys. an example is, if there are 30 shops, we will have

image1 shop 30

code is :

```
    Resources rsc = getActivity().getResources();
        String[] options = rsc.getStringArray(R.array.item_title);
        TypedArray icons = rsc.obtainTypedArray(R.array.item_title_color);
  HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_custom_item, options, icons, map);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

MyAdapter class:

```
class MyAccountsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private int ViewResourceId; 
        private String[] mstring;
        TypedArray icons;
        HashMap<String, String> infomap = new HashMap<String,String>();

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] string, TypedArray icons, HashMap<String, String> map) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, string);

      mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
              mstring = string;
              this.icons = icons;
              ViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
              infomap.putAll(map);  //another hashmap here
        }

    @Override
        public int getCount(){
            return mstring.length;
        }

            @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(ViewResourceId, null);

            ImageView imageview = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image_id);
            TextView text_title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_text_id);
            TextView text_info = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_textinfo_id);

            imageview.setImageDrawable(icons.getDrawable(position));
            text_title.setText(mstring[position]);
            Log.d(TAG, "strings are" + text_title.getText().toString());

// so how do i populate text_info here to correspond with text_title;

            return convertView;
        }
```

any ideas? or is there a better way to do this like combine them all into one?..  any help is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: If the keys in the map are the values for the first `TextView` what is stopping you from using `text_info.setText(infomap.get(mstring[position]))` in the `getView` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code :

```
   text_info.setText(infomap.get(mstring[position]));
```

Comment: sorry for the very late response. but apparently its returning null values when i do that.